# How to find matching pair of data in NHibernate QueryOver?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have two lists.

```
AccountNumbers  ["account1", "account2", "account3"]
Descriptions [ "desc1",  "" ] (possible should be empty value)
```

And I have two database tables `Account` and `AccountDescriptionHistory`. Tables have a relation with `accountId`.

Account Table Design:-
AccountId , AccountNumber, Description,

Account Description history :-
AccountId, Description, validTo, validFrom

Now, I want to design a **Nhibernet Query** with a query over with below requirement.

1. `Account` table should join with `AccountDescriptionHistory` on left join with `accountId` column.
2. Account Number should be filtered from the list of passing `accountnumbers`.
3. Description should be matched from the passing list of `descriptions` and
   select description from `accountdescriptionhistory` table if passing param `dateToCheck` is
   greater than and less than of `validFrom` and `validTo` columns of `accountdescriptionhistory`
   otherwise, select from `account` table.
4. Consider empty and lower case value from database column

I have tried with the below query but don't know how to filter from collections.

```
        public IEnumerable<Account> CheckForExistingAccounts(ISession session, Owner owner, IEnumerable<string> accountNumbers,
        IEnumerable<string> descriptions, bool isUpdating, DateTime? dateToCheck = null)
    {
        Account accountAlias = null;
        AccountDescriptionHistory accountDescripAlias = null;


        var existingaccountsquery = session.queryover(() => accountalias).
                                joinentityalias(() => accountdescripalias, () => accountdescripalias.account.id == accountalias.id, jointype.leftouterjoin).
                                where(account => !account.isdeleted && account.owner.id == owner.id).
                                selectlist(list => list
                                        .select(() => accountalias.id).withalias(() => accountalias.id)
                                        .select(projections.conditional(expression.isnull(
                                                projections.property(accountalias.accountnumber)),
                                                projections.property(string.empty),
                                                projections.property(string.empty))).withalias(() => accountalias.accountnumber)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.changed).withalias(() => accountalias.changed)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.created).withalias(() => accountalias.created)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.sequencenumber).withalias(() => accountalias.sequencenumber)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.accounttype).withalias(() => accountalias.accounttype)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.parentaccount).withalias(() => accountalias.parentaccount)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.coreaccountid).withalias(() => accountalias.coreaccountid)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.sourceid).withalias(() => accountalias.sourceid)
                                        .select(() => accountalias.description).withalias(() => accountalias.description)
                                ).transformusing(new deeptransformer<account>()).future<account>();



        var data = existingaccountsquery.List();

        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed the query for the above descriptive problem OR question. i am posting here if it helps in the future to other developers.

```
`var existingAccountsQuery = session.QueryOver(() => accountAlias)
        .JoinEntityAlias(() => accountDescripAlias,
                    Restrictions.And
                    (
                        //And clause 1
                        Restrictions.EqProperty($"{nameof(accountAlias)}.{nameof(accountAlias.Id)}",
                        "accountDescripAlias.Account.Id"),
                        //And clause 2
                        Restrictions.And(
                            Restrictions.Le(
                                Projections.SqlFunction("date",
                                    NHibernateUtil.Date,
                                    Projections.Property(
                                    $"{nameof(accountDescripAlias)}.{nameof(accountDescripAlias.ValidFrom)}"))
                            , dateToCheck),
                        Restrictions.Ge(
                                Projections.SqlFunction("date",
                                    NHibernateUtil.Date,
                                    Projections.Property(
                                    $"{nameof(accountDescripAlias)}.{nameof(accountDescripAlias.ValidFrom)}"))
                            , dateToCheck)
                            )
                    ),
                JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .Where(() => !accountAlias.IsDeleted && accountAlias.Owner.Id == owner.Id)
        .Where(() => accountAlias.AccountNumber == null || accountAlias.AccountNumber.Lower().IsIn(accountNumbers.ToArray()))
        .Where(() =>
            (
                accountDescripAlias.AccountDescription != null &&
                accountDescripAlias.ValidFrom <= dateToCheck && accountDescripAlias.ValidTo >= dateToCheck &&
                accountDescripAlias.AccountDescription.Lower().IsIn(descriptions.ToArray())
            ) ||
            (
                accountDescripAlias.AccountDescription == null &&
                accountAlias.Description != null &&
                accountAlias.Description.Lower().IsIn(descriptions.ToArray())
            ) ||
            (
                accountDescripAlias.AccountDescription == null &&
                accountAlias.Description == null
            )
        );`
```